# Keep staging Blobs in Data Lake after copy activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, polybase

I've been copying date into Synapse using the copy data functionality in Azure data factory (polybase), with staging enabled to stage the data in our azure data lake. However, once the copy into Synapse is complete the staging files in our azure data lake get deleted.

Is there any way to keep the staged files in the data lake after the copy activity has finished, rather than deleting?

Answer (score 0):

As per the document, the staged data gets cleaned up after the data movement to the sink is completed.

[Copy activity performance optimization features - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features#how-staged-copy-works)

If you want to copy data to data lake storage, you can use other copy activity and store the data in data lake storage as sink data store.

Comment: Thanks, that is actually our current solution. It seems a little counter intuitive to to go from source - data lake (staging) - Synapse, and then separately go from source-data lake?